# Strange memory layout when creating constants in NASM

Tags: assembly, nasm

Consider the following assembler code for a partial boot loader:

```
bits 16
org 0x7C00

msg_init db 'Initializing...', 0Ah, 0Dh, 0
msg_completed db 'Completed', 0Ah, 0Dh, 0

jmp start

start:
    xor ax, ax              
    mov ds, ax              
    mov es, ax              

    mov si, msg_init        
    call print              

    mov si, msg_completed   
    call print              

    mov al, '*'
    mov bx, 0
    mov ah, 0Eh
    int 10h

    cli
    hlt

print:
    lodsb                   ; al = [ds:si] - char to write
    or al, al               ; set zero flag if al=0
    jz return               ; jump to return if zero flag set
    mov bx, 0               ; bh = page #, bl = color
    mov ah, 0Eh             ; function = teletype output
    int 10h             ; video interrupt
    jmp print               ; print next char if not zero

return:
    ret                 ; return

times 510-($-$$) db 0
dw 0xAA55
```

The memory layout looks like this:

```
0000: 49 6e 69 74 69 61 6c 69-7a 69 6e 67 2e 2e 2e 0a Initializing....
0010: 0d 00 43 6f 6d 70 6c 65-74 65 64 0a 0d 00 e9 00 ..Completed.....
0020: 00 31 c0 8e d8 8e c0 be-00 7c e8 11 00 be 12 7c .1.......|.....|
0030: e8 0b 00 b0 2a bb 00 00-b4 0e cd 10 fa f4 ac 08 ....*...........
0040: c0 74 09 bb 00 00 b4 0e-cd 10 eb f2 c3 00 00 00 .t..............
```

When I change the `msg_completed` constant to "Enabled" i.e. `msg_completed db 'Enabled', 0Ah, 0Dh, 0` the memory layout changes to:

```
0000: 00 f0 e3 fe 00 00 2e 0a-00 00 15 7c 00 00 57 2a ...........|..W*
0010: 0d 00 45 6e 61 62 6c 65-64 0a 0d 00 e9 00 00 31 ..Enabled......1
0020: c0 8e d8 8e c0 be 00 7c-e8 11 00 be 12 7c e8 0b .......|.....|..
0030: 00 b0 2a bb 00 00 b4 0e-cd 10 fa f4 ac 08 c0 74 ..*............t
0040: 09 bb 00 00 b4 0e cd 10-eb f2 c3 00 00 00 00 00 ................
```

It seems the first few bytes are overwritten. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't observe such behavior (tried "version 0.98.36 compiled on Jun 13 2003" and "version 2.09.10 compiled on Jul 15 2011" on Windows XP). "Initializing" is there in all 4 binaries.

Are you sure you didn't change anything else? And the binary in the second case is what NASM output, not what you read back from media?

Btw, your code isn't going to work. The CPU will start executing the boot sector from its very beginning, from `db 'Initializing...', 0Ah, 0Dh, 0`. That's data, not code.

Also, it would be a good thing to ensure that `CS=0` and `IP>=0x7C00` early in the code (some BIOSes jump to `0x7C0:0` instead of `0:0x7C00`) and clear `FLAGS.DF` with `CLD` prior to `LODSB`.

Comment: The issue seemed to be exactly what you said. The execution started with the data. I moved it to the bottom of the file before the bootsector signature and it now seems fine. Thank you.